# Convert bytes to string or number in Python

Tags: python, string, byte

I want to get the first 6 bytes from payload as a single number or string.

```
for byte_pos in range(6):
   byte_content  = ord(payload[byte_pos])
```

Assume the payload is 1 2 3 4 5 6,

```
for byte_pos in range(6):
   print ord(payload[byte_pos])
```

This will result as follows,
0x1
0x2
0x3
0x4
0x5
0x6

But what I need is a single number/string like 123456. How to combine these single numbers to make 123456?

How to convert these 6 byte_contents to a single number or string.

Comment: An example would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading bytes, it means you are reading integers from 0 to 255. So you can turn those numbers quickly to base-10 like this : `int(str(byte), 2)`

If you want to turn bytes into characters, you might use the chr() function : `char = chr(int(str(byte), 2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Python 2.x here's an answer (if I understood what you want to do) :

```
payload  = bytearray(b'\x41\x42\x43') #Hex code for ABC
final_string = ''


for byte_pos in range(3):
   byte_content  = chr(payload[byte_pos])
   #print byte_content
   final_string = final_string + byte_content
   print final_string
```

Output will be :

```
A
AB
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dst_mac = ''
for byte_pos in range(6):
    dst_mac = dst_mac + str(hex((ord(payload[byte_pos])))[2:])
print dst_mac
```

This way, it worked.

Thank you